# Carriage return doesnt work properly when redirecting output to file python

Tags: python, command-line

I have this simple code in which each iteration is overwriting the output of previous line:

```
import time
for i in reversed(range (12)):
    print i, '\r',
    time.sleep(0.2)
```

when I run the script using the command: `python test.py` I see the output is replacing itself each iteration as expected. 
However when I redirect the output to a file using the command:

```
python test.py >> tmp.txt
```

I get a file containing all 12 numbers in 12 separate lines.

How can I achieve the same final result in output file as if I ran the script from command line?

I use python 2.6.5 on windows 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do that because redirection appends data to the end of the file.

What's written is written.

Edit: BUT there are workarounds.

### number one: change your python code

```
import time,sys

interactive = sys.stdout.isatty()

for i in reversed(range (12)):
    if i==0 or interactive:
        print i, '\r',
    time.sleep(0.2)
```

When redirected to a file, it will only print `0`. If ran without redirection, it will perform like before.

### number two: add a filter

If you're running Linux or Windows with MSYS installed, just pipe the output to a command like `cat`

```
python test.py | cat >> tmp.txt
```

only `0` will be echoed to the file

Comment: all I want is to see only the last line of output in the output file. Is it absolutely impossible? Maybe flush later..

Answer (score 1):

When you run your script from the command line, the terminal interprets the `\r` character and moves the cursor to the beginning of the line.  The actual bytes in the output from your Python script is the same.  You can use `cat tmp.txt` to "replay" the file through the terminal, to achieve much the same effect as when running the script interactively; but it appears that what you *really* want cannot be done so simply.

To rewrite the bytes you have already written to the output file, close and reopen it, or `seek()` back to the beginning before the next write.

Needless to say, if you currently don't have a file, just a file handle (like standard output), the required changes to your program are rather invasive.